# Having difficulty creating my own custom view

Tags: android, view, extends

So I'm trying to create my own view outside of xml layouts and am having difficulty getting it to display anything.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but cannot see what it might be.  Any input is appreciated.  Here are my two classes I'm using for testing purposes.

```
public class TestSuite extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Turns off the application title at the top..
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // Turns off the status bar at the top..
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(new Background(this));
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Background extends View {

    public Background(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public Background(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public Background(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Resources res = getResources();

        Rect baseRectBounds = new Rect(0,0,200,200);
        Rect topRectBounds = new Rect(20,20,160,160);
        Rect bottomRectBounds = new Rect(40,40,120,120);

        Paint baseColor = new Paint(res.getColor(R.color.blue));
        Paint topColor = new Paint(res.getColor(R.color.red));
        Paint bottomColor = new Paint(res.getColor(R.color.green));

        canvas.drawRect(baseRectBounds, baseColor);
        canvas.drawRect(topRectBounds, topColor);
        canvas.drawRect(bottomRectBounds, bottomColor);
    }

}
```

*edit*

Here's the newest onDraw method I'm working with.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Resources res = getResources();

    Rect canvasBounds = canvas.getClipBounds();

    Log.v("CanvasBounds before", "left - " + canvasBounds.left);
    Log.v("CanvasBounds before", "top - " + canvasBounds.top);
    Log.v("CanvasBounds before", "right - " + canvasBounds.right);
    Log.v("CanvasBounds before", "bottom - " + canvasBounds.bottom);

    Rect baseRect = new Rect(0,0,200,200);
    Rect topRect = new Rect(20,20,160,160);
    Rect botRect = new Rect(40,40,120,120);

    Paint baseColor = new Paint(res.getColor(R.color.red)); 
    Paint topColor = new Paint(res.getColor(R.color.green));
    Paint botColor = new Paint(res.getColor(R.color.blue));
    baseColor.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    topColor.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    botColor.setStyle(Style.FILL);

    canvas.drawRect(baseRect, baseColor);
    canvas.drawRect(topRect, topColor);
    canvas.drawRect(botRect, botColor);

    canvasBounds = canvas.getClipBounds();

    Log.v("CanvasBounds after", "left - " + canvasBounds.left);
    Log.v("CanvasBounds after", "top - " + canvasBounds.top);
    Log.v("CanvasBounds after", "right - " + canvasBounds.right);
    Log.v("CanvasBounds after", "bottom - " + canvasBounds.bottom);
}
```

The results of the Log statements are as follows:

```
CanvasBounds before left - 0
CanvasBounds before top - 0
CanvasBounds before right - 480
CanvasBounds before bottom - 800
CanvasBounds after  left - 0
CanvasBounds after  top - 0
CanvasBounds after  right - 480
CanvasBounds after  bottom - 800
```

*finished edit*

Thanks to Ted's help, here's my final onDraw method (for others who might need it).

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Resources res = getResources();

    Rect baseRect = new Rect(0,0,200,200);
    Rect topRect = new Rect(20,20,160,160);
    Rect botRect = new Rect(40,40,120,120);

    Paint color = new Paint();

    color.setColor(res.getColor(R.color.red));
    canvas.drawRect(baseRect, color);
    color.setColor(res.getColor(R.color.blue));
    canvas.drawRect(topRect, color);
    color.setColor(res.getColor(R.color.green));
    canvas.drawRect(botRect, color);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. in your c'tor, call `setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(FILL_PARENT, FILL_PARENT))` (here, `LayoutParams` is `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`)
2. override `measure(int,int)` and implement it as suggested in the [docs for `View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

Comment: Ok..  So I added `setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.FILL_PARENT));` into all 3 constructors and then overrode `onMeasure(int, int)` (the docs said you had to override onMeasure) with `super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);  int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec); int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec); setMeasuredDimensions(width, height);` but it still shows up as a blank screen.  I even added some Log.v statements to see what width and height were returning, and they were correct values. :T

Comment: Er ... my `ViewGroup.FILL_PARENT` up there should be `LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT`.  Typo on my part.

Comment: If it's still not appearing, try using [Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html) to inspect your layout while it's running in an emulator. It might help diagnose whether this is a layout problem or a rendering problem.

Comment: I loaded up Hierarchy Viewer and went to "Load View Hierarchy" and when I told it to display on white it showed the expected rectangles drawn .. but they were black in color .. not the color I have specified in my paint.  So ... at least I know it's drawing the rectangles .. now I just don't know why it's not COLORING them..  (I have added `color.setStyle(Style.FILL)` to all of my paints, also, and it isn't filling them in).  I appreciate your help, btw.  I'm not new to programming, but definitely new to Android and this has been giving me a headache for a couple of weeks now.

Comment: Make sure that your color resources are defined as opaque colors. If that's not it, try logging calls to your `onDraw` method. Include the canvas's clip bounds in the log data.

Comment: My xml for the colors are red = #FFFF0000, green = #FF00FF00, blue = #FF0000FF.  (FF is fully opaque, right? and 00 is fully transparent?)  Um .. I'm not sure what you're referring to by Canvas clip bounds, though.  Are you referring to what the left, top, right, and bottom values for the canvas are?  Or something else?  (child dragging me outside for a bit.  bbiaw)

Comment: Yes, FF is opaque. Forget about clip bounds; I think I see the problem. You are creating your Paint objects by passing the color value to the c'tor. That won't work because the c'tor will interpret it as flags for setting its internal state. Create a single Paint object and use `setColor` to set it to each color just before drawing each rectangle.

Comment: O frabjous day! Callooh! Callay!  That worked!  Yeesh - I knew it was gonna be something simple that I was missing.  Thanks so much, Ted!

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I'm just sorry I didn't see that right at the start.